# Zend Framework 2 / Navigation / set parent menu active when child page access

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have this navigation configuration :

```
        [
            'label'           => 'Home',
            'route'           => 'application',
            'use_route_match' => true,
        ],
        [
            'label'           => 'Users',
            'route'           => 'application/users/list',
            'use_route_match' => true,
            'pages' =>
                [
                    ['route' => 'application/users/list', 'visible' => false],
                ]
        ],
```

On my UserController, indexAction() redirects to listAction()

The navigation is displayed with a partial, such as that :

```
<ul class="list-inline">

    <?php

        /**
         * @var $page \Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc
         */
        foreach($this->container->getPages() as $page):

            if(!$page->isVisible() || !$this->navigation()->accept($page)) continue;

            $isActive = false;
            $classes = [];

            $href = $page->getHref();

            if($page->isActive(true))
            {
                $isActive = true;
                $classes[] = 'active';
            }

            ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?= $href ?>" <?= ($classes) ? ' class="' . implode(' ', $classes) . '"' : '' ?>>
                    <?= $page->label ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
</ul>
```

For the home page menu, it works, but when I access to the "users list" page menu, "active" class is not applied ...

What's wrong ?